# Trying to integrate lightGallery with lightSlider

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to integrate lightGallery with lightSlider on my Wordpress website, following the instructions on this page
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html

However, I can't seem to get it to work. These are the codes I'm using.

single.php

```
<?php   
// ACF Fields
// tl_slide_images = Gallery Field
function themeprefix_lightslider_thumbslider() {
$images = get_field('gallery'); //add your correct field name
    if( $images ): ?>

        <ul id="imageGallery" class="image-gallery">

        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

            <li data-thumb="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
               <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
            </li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; 
}

      themeprefix_lightslider_thumbslider(); ?>
```

lightslider-init.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({ 
        gallery:true, 
        item:1, 
        auto:false, 
        loop:true, 
        thumbItem: 9,
        enableDrag: false,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      slideMove: 1,
      auto: false,
      speed: 800,
      pause: 4000,  

   onSliderLoad: function(el) {
            el.lightGallery({
                selector: '#imageGallery .lSSlide'
            });
        }   
    });  
  });
```

I have filed lightGallery.js and lightGallery.css and try to call them with

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightGallery.css" />                  
<script src="js/lightGallery.js"></script>
```

However, I suspect this is where it goes wrong, since my lightSlider is called with the following code in functions.php

```
/**
 * LightSlider Scripts
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ls_scripts_styles', 20 );

function ls_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'lightslidercss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/lightslider.min.css' , array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lightsliderjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightslider.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lightsliderinit', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightslider-init.js', array( 'lightsliderjs' ), '1.0.0', true );

}
```

Can anyone help me? Please note that I'm still a beginner on this.